# How to use hashtable key-value and array in import vapp command?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Here is my hashtable with the below key-values,

```
$hostHash = @{3 = 'HostPC-1','HostPC-3','HostPC-5' ; 2 = 'HostPC-2','HostPC-4'}
```

I have 2 esxi machines and stored its IP addresses in the below array,

```
$esxarr = @(10.91.91.x18, 10.91.91.x19)
```

I'm trying to deploy 3 VMs in 10.91.91.x18 and 2 VMs in 10.91.91.x19 simultaneously, and below is my code to achieve my objective but I'm facing issues while iterating the keys-values.

```
$esxflag = 0
$hostHash.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
$nn = $_.Value
for($it = 0; $it -le $nn.Length-1) {
Import-VApp -Source $hostpcpath -Name $nn[$it] -DiskStorageFormat Thin -VMHost $esxarray[$esxflag] -Datastore 'SSD'
    $esxflag = $esxflag+1
    $it = $it + 1
  }
}
```

please help me to apply a logic to read the values('HostPC-1','HostPC-3','HostPC-5') of 1st key and to deploy the VMs in `10.91.91.x18(esxi machine 1)` and values('HostPC-2','HostPC-4') of 2nd key in 10.91.91.x19(esxi machine 2)

Comment: Handle IPAddresses as string `$esxarr = @('10.91.91.x18', '10.91.91.x19')
` without `'` or `"` Powershell doesn't understand the array.

Comment: To count the number of elements in an array better use `.Count` instead of `.Length`. If you have just one element, `length` will return the length of the string (number of chars of the string). `Count` will count 1 element.

Comment: How exactly do you get the lists of VMs that shall be imported on which esx server? Are they fix lists or rather dynamic generated? Is it something like every second VM goes to the other Server? In the current example the easy way would be to tell `esx1` to import all of (`foreach`) `$hostHash.3` and the other server to import `foreach` in `$hostHash.2`. Shell the Vms be (re-)named in a specific way during import?

Comment: $hosthash is a dynamic hashtable as it is user input based, at some instance, I might even use more than 4 ESXi machines. Also I have not found the exact method to the VMs that shall be imported on to its respective esx server

Comment: Should each array in `$hostHash` be hardcoded to an ESXi Server? Or how do you want to decide which array belongs to which server? BTW: `Foreach` is not executing simultaneously but successive. If you want to execute it simultaneously you would need [jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd315273(v=technet.10)) or [powershell 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/)

Comment: $hosthash is not hardcoded to an esx server. i wanna decide which array belong to which server. And I have not found the way to do so

Comment: I would go for a `foreach  ( $esxServer in $esxArr) {` import `foreach` in `$hostHash` where the name is the one you choose `}`. And  I would recommend to rename the items in `$hostHash`. `2` and `3` are rather inexpressive.